# dbMail concatenated url parsing ampersand as word and

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ampersand, dbmail

I'm using dbmail to gather data and send an email. As a part of that email, I have a url surrounding text for a clickable link to an SSRS report with parameters. If I only have one parameter, I'm fine. But, if I add parameters, the url is passed with the ampersand being replaced by "and". I've tried the text &, char(38), and text %26 and it parses it the same by converting it to the word "and".

For example, if the url is collated using

```
declare @MySQL as varchar(max)='<table><tr><td>
<a href=' + char(39) + 'https://blah/Reports_SSRS/report/subfolder1/Subfolder%20Stuff/report%20Name?svcMeasure=' + cast(met.measureID as varchar(2)) + '&svcProv=' + z.abbrv + char(39) +'>' + measureTitle + '</a></td></tr></table>'
```

What's rendered is 
    https://blah/reports_ssrs/report/subfolder1/subfolder stuff/report name?svcMeasure=8andsvcProv=brown'>my measure

```
     set @tableHTML = @tableHTML + 
 N'<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2"><tr><td colspan="5" bgcolor="#68cbd0"><b>Table Title</b> </td></tr>' +
 CAST((SELECT  case when rs2.myBG='a' then '#F0FFF0' else '#FFC0CB' end  as [@bgcolor], 
 td  = cast(rs2.measureUrl as xml), '',  
 'center' as 'td/@align',td = '(of '+ convert(varchar(5),rs2.myPeerCount) +')',''  
 from (blah blah blah)rs2 FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +  N'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `&amp;` html version in place of `&`

```
    declare @MySQL as varchar(max)='<table><tr><td>
    <a href=' + char(39) + 'https://blah/Reports_SSRS/report/subfolder1/Subfolder%20Stuff/report%20Name?svcMeasure=' + cast(met.measureID as varchar(2)) + '&amp;svcProv=' + z.abbrv + char(39) +'>' + measureTitle + '</a></td></tr></table>'
```

Comment: Well, I've done some digging and I've got additional info.  I apologize if the original post was misleading.  I'm gathering the data and inserting into a temp table for manipulation and then pulling it back out to send as an email in dbMail.  The data appears correctly in the temp table.  I believe I've done something just a tad incorrectly in the parsing of the xml for the html table format in the email.

Comment: I edited the original post - it's the td  = cast(rs2.measureUrl as xml), '', 
line that I think is my problem.  If I leave that, I get an error now of XML parsing: line 1, character 169, illegal name character.  If I take it out, the email goes through, but the url is written as text and not a clickable hyperlink?  Thanks and sorry for the confusion.  The "and" was being changed

Comment: What I finally got to work was to create the url, but skip the & between parameters
     http://tada/folder/reportName?param1=blahparam2=blah
Then parse it for the html with 
     td=cast(replace(rs2.measureUrl,'&','and') as xml), '',  
Then just before I send the dbMail, do this
     set @tableHTML=replace(@tableHTML,'param2','&amp;param2=')

Answer (score 0):

What I finally got to work was to create the url, but skip the & between parameters

```
http://tada/folder/reportName?param1=blahparam2=blah
```

Then parse it for the html with

```
td=cast(replace(rs2.measureUrl,'&','and') as xml), '',
```

Then just before I send the dbMail, do this

```
set @tableHTML=replace(@tableHTML,'param2','&param2=')
```

Probably not kosher, but it works!